# Code executing continously

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index

In this site , when i put the alerts after this line:

```
$('dateRange').update(jsonData[xmin].date + ' - ' + jsonData[xmax].date);

alert(date1); alert(date2);
```

The alerts are being executed contionusly , please tell me how to avoid this.

Comment: Continuously as opposed to...?

Comment: Does it stop if you don't have your mouse over a graph? It seems that it's hooking on to the DOM element, so if you're moving your mouse it may execute it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code inside Event.observe executed continously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896519/code-inside-event-observe-executed-continously)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `alert` try having such code:

```
$('dateRange').update(jsonData[xmin].date + ' - ' + jsonData[xmax].date);
var oDiv = document.createElement("div");
oDiv.innerHTML = date1 + "<br />" + date2;
document.body.appendChild(oDiv);
```

This will add the debug information to the existing document so you can still see it, and won't break any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the custom event `'flotr:select'` fires continuously while the date range slider is being moved. When you finish dragging the date range there may be 10's even 100's of 'flotr:select' events fired and thus an awful lot of alert boxes queued up.

I think you need to change that event for one that just fires once after the date range has changed (if there is one).

...

`Event.observe(HumbleFinance.containers.summary, 'flotr:select', function...` this function is called many times per second when the date range is being adjusted